# Conditional use of CefSharp if VC++ Redistribuable is installed

Tags: .net, winforms, cefsharp

I have trouble with using CefSharp. Well not really in fact. CefSharp is well installed ad configured on my application (multi CPU configured) and works very well. It is a winform application and I use CefSharp to display some statistics to my end users that are calculated by a webApi. But it is a very very small part of my app and not all my users have this option.
But the problem is CefSharp use VC++ Redistribuable, and some of my users do not have it installed (and sometimes we cannot install it on the machine because the system administrator does not allow us to do so). But the way is that if I launch my application in this case, it crashed !!!

I have put a verification in the first line of my Program.cs (the first line reading while running the app) to check if VC++ installed or not to disable the option, but I can't reach this point, the application crash before that, while attempting to load CefSharp DLL even if I would not use it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        isVC2015to2019x86Installed = CRedistributableChecker.CRedistributablePackage.IsInstalled(CRedistributableChecker.RedistributablePackageVersion.VC2015to2019x86) ||
                                    CRedistributableChecker.CRedistributablePackage.IsInstalled(CRedistributableChecker.RedistributablePackageVersion.VC2015x86) ||
                                    CRedistributableChecker.CRedistributablePackage.IsInstalled(CRedistributableChecker.RedistributablePackageVersion.VC2017x86);

        if (isVC2015to2019x86Installed)
        {
            //Need to start the assembly with the right environment(x32 or x64) because this dll does not support any cpu compilation
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
            var settings = new CefSharp.WinForms.CefSettings()
            {
                BrowserSubprocessPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
                               Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86",
                               "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe")
            };
            CefSharp.CefSharpSettings.ShutdownOnExit = false;
            CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("test");
```

And I know that it is the combination of CefSharp and VC++ because if I delete all reference to it, or if I install VCC++, the application is launching perfectly.

Is there a way to load conditionnally CefSharp if VC++ is installed or not? Or at least a way to run the application ...

Thanks by advance.

Comment: CefSharp requires a bunch of native DLLs to be deployed.  The VC++ runtime DLLs are just part of that, nothing special.  Do *not* insist on the user running the redist installer, just include them.  Copied locally to your install directory.

Comment: You can bin deploy vc++, there are some links in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Including_vcredist with additional information.

Comment: The problem is that for the moment we do not have a clean deployment application. Some updates are down by the projects manager by replacing DLL directly in the app folder. We work on it ....

Comment: See section 6 of https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/

Comment: If you absolutely have to use runtime checking then you'll have to restructure your code,  all calls to CefSharp need to be in a different method, mark that method with [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] so the compiler doesn't inline the method.

Comment: Mark the method will not change anything. I have comment all references to the CefSharp Code, the simple fact to have the DLL loaded in the csproj cause the crash.

Comment: Including a reference in your project doesn't actually load the dlls. You likely have code somewhere else in your project. Anyway,  I suggest bin deploying VC++